# Trying to create single bash file which will start mentioned node applications

Tags: node.js, bash, automation

I have 3 node applications i am trying to start all of these applications by running single bash file.

I have all this three node apps in `/apps` folder.

```
app1 - /app/app1
app2 - /app/app2
app3 - /app/app3
```

Comment: Put that in a file and remove the dashes `-` then `bash ./my_file_with_node_content` or create a script and make it executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be fairly simple. In your `execute-multiple.sh` file you can put:

```
node app/app1.js &
node app/app2.js &
node app/app3.js &
```

Call it with `sh execute-multiple.sh` form your `apps` folder.